# CNContactPickerViewController gets error (CNPropertyNotFetchedException) - Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, ios9, cncontact

I am calling the Contact Picker View like so:

```
- (void)openContacts {
    CNContactPickerViewController *picker = [[CNContactPickerViewController alloc] init];

    picker.delegate = self;

    picker.displayedPropertyKeys = @[CNContactGivenNameKey];

    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

And I am handling the selections with this delegate method:

```
- (void)contactPicker:(CNContactPickerViewController *)picker didSelectContacts:(NSArray<CNContact *> *)contacts {
    for (CNContact *contact in contacts) {
        NSLog(@"%@",contact);
        NSString *phone;
        NSString *mobilePhone;

        for (CNLabeledValue *label in contact.phoneNumbers) {
            if ([label.label isEqualToString:CNLabelPhoneNumberMobile] || [label.label isEqualToString:CNLabelPhoneNumberiPhone]) {
                mobilePhone = [label.value stringValue];
            } else if ([label.label isEqualToString:CNLabelPhoneNumberMain]) {
                phone = [label.value stringValue];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The NSLog outputs the following for contact: `<CNContact: 0x78e56e50: identifier=1861C9BD-143B-4E93-8475-F9079F5D6192, givenName=Kate, familyName=Bell, organizationName=Creative Consulting, phoneNumbers=(not fetched), emailAddresses=(not fetched), postalAddresses=(not fetched)>`

This only occurs on simulator and iOS9 iPad. I don't get an error with my iOS10 iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

You should first ask permission for this. Then you can show picker.

```
CNContactStore *store = [[CNContactStore alloc] init];
[store requestAccessForEntityType:CNEntityTypeContacts completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error)
 {
         CNContactPickerViewController *picker = [[CNContactPickerViewController alloc] init];
         picker.delegate = self;
         picker.displayedPropertyKeys = @[CNContactGivenNameKey];
         [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
 }];
```

In this case you'll show picker always, without dependance on user's choice. So you should check property availability like that:

```
if ([CNContactStore authorizationStatusForEntityType:CNEntityTypeContacts] == CNAuthorizationStatusAuthorized)
    {

    }
```